# Is it possible for the executable to ask for Administrator rights? (Windows 7)

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7

I am developing a partition disk program, and for me to read the `\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0` I need admin rights.

I am wondering if it is possible, in the run time, for the program to gain admin rights? Is there any win api for that?

I want to do that because I want the program to execute with admin rights only when it is reading/writing the disk. For security reasons, I don't want the program to execute all the time with admin rights, because someone could find a bug (stack or heap overflow for example) in some module and execute arbitrary commands as adm.

Comment: No.  You would have to move that code into another .exe project that has a manifest that asks for the UAC elevation permission.  Start that .exe when necessary.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers! The trick of separating the process will do the job.

Comment: @HansPassant: Not necessarily _another_ .exe. Look at Task Manager, which restarts itself with Administrator rights if you choose "view processes for all users".

Comment: @MSalters - True.  But that's autoElevate at work, not available to mere mortals.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.07.uac.aspx#id0560031

Comment: @HansPassant: The _autoElevate_ is reserved to the OS, but that's just to suppress a prompt.

Comment: @HansPassant: It just re runs itself with the "runas" verb which elevates (and prompts if required)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot acquire elevated privileges after the process has started. Your options are:

1. Put the part of your application that requires elevated privileges into a separate process and manifest that with `requireAdministrator`.
2. Run the part of your application that requires elevated privileges as an out-of-proc COM object.

Comment: See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679687(v=vs.85).aspx) on MSDN for the COM elevation method.

Answer (score 4):

I have never seen a way to transition rights once a process has begun executing.  The only way I know of is for the process to be created as privileged.

I look forward to other answers in case there is another way.

(update)
The article [*Teach Your Apps To Play Nicely With Windows Vista User Account Control*](https://web.archive.org/web/20150201112642/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163486.aspx) (about halfway down) confirms that admin rights can be granted only at process creation time.

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

You need to embed manifest with requireAdministrator flag

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx

Comment: Well as the program requires access to low level computer parts, I don't see any reason why shouldn't it run with admin priviliges. Same reason would apply to privilged subprocess launched everytime that priviliged operation needs to be done

Comment: For exactly the same reason that OpenSSH isn't running everything with root rights, just because it has to listen at port 22.. anything else is horrible design and violates one of the most basic principles of secure code design. [There's even a wiki article about it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_separation)

Comment: "Partition program" itself is launched to perform some administrator priviliged operations. Partitioning itself requires admin priviliges.

Comment: And there are obviously other things the program does that do not need admin rights - after all that's what the whole question is about!

Answer (score 0):

Project's Propeties (Alt + Enter) `->` Linker `->` Manifest File
 `->` UAC Execution level (in VS2015, in 2010 it's similar)
  `->` requireAdministrator or highestAvailable

Edit: Also, if it's updating program, simply make your program's name starting with `Update` and Windows will automatically recognize it.