# Requesting administrator privileges in C program?

Tags: c, windows, administrator

I'm trying to make a C program that modifies my host file, but I can't just straight up open the file with the program, because Windows blocks it. Is there any way that I can make the program request administrative privileges within the code, or any script I can use to start the program in admin mode?

Answer (score 1):

Right clicking is a solution that allows you to run any program with Administrator privileges. That includes ticking the box in "Properties".

On Windows 7 and later, you can also rename your program so that its name contains `setup` (like `hosts_setup.exe`), and it'll automatically be run in Administrator mode (brings up the UAC prompt) if double-clicked in Explorer. Note this only works from double-clicking in Explorer.

<s>You can also take a look at [How can I run a child process that requires elevation and wait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4893262/5958455) . It calls WinAPI and is a fairly native approach.</s> The best solution is to [add it in menifest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8916084/5958455) so your program requests Admin at startup.

Comment: I am not a Windows user, but I need to ask: does this mean that after you run it like that the user is asked to input the windows administrator password. Or I am wrong?

Comment: @Michi It brings up the UAC prompt. Nothing slips past that.

Comment: @Michi, if manifested as `requireAdministrator`, then `CreateProcess` fails with `ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED` if the caller isn't already elevated. The caller can retry via `ShellExecuteEx` with the "runas" action. This sends the request to a system service named "Application Information", which runs consent.exe (the UAC dialog) on the secure Desktop of the requesting Session. If it gets consent, the service calls `CreateProcessAsUser` to run the elevated process in the given Session. Console applications allocate an elevated console (conhost.exe instance) instead of inheriting the parent's.

Comment: The manifest can be added externally, without requiring a tool such as mt.exe to embed it as a resource in the executable. If the file is named "foo.exe", then name the manifest beside it as "foo.exe.manifest".

Answer (score 0):

Shoot, okay, seconds after posting this question, I found a solution. It turns out that you can right click the executable, click properties, and on the compatibility tab, select "Run this program as administrator". Just in case anyone else needed this information.

Comment: I'm not sure that answers your question

Comment: It answers the first sentence, but avoids the second by external means.